# Magento 2 Rest API get customer ID from session token (React Native App)

Tags: magento, magento2

I am working on a React Native app, I cannot see in the API files or docs on how to retrieve a customers ID from the session token after they have logged into the app or any other customer information.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to target this the endpoint `YOUR_HOST.com/rest/V1/customers/me` with the headers:

```
{
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "Bearer adkfvllaskYOUR_SESSION_TOKENasdfasf"
}
```